# How to set MongoDB ReadPreference in Spring MVC's contextConfigLocation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, sharding

I am connecting to a MongoDB sharding server via mongodb java driver in Spring MVC. I am using the following versions:

- spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE
- mongo-java-driver/2.10.0/mongo-java-driver-2.10.0
- spring-data-mongodb-1.2.0.RELEASE

My Mongo options are set in the contextConfigLocation file mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mongo:mongo host="mongo.sample.com" port="30000">
     <mongo:options auto-connect-retry="true"
                    slave-ok="true"/>
</mongo:mongo>
```

It works pretty well, but the slave-ok is deprecated by come.MongoDB.ReadPreference.  I just wonder if there is any way to set the readPreference for Spring MVC in the contextConfiLocation file.

Comment: You can set it via `mongoTemplate` for sure

Comment: Looking at the schema (http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd) you can only set slave-ok, there's no "secondary preferred" option (which is the replacement).  You'll be OK using slave-ok, it's still supported in the Mongo driver despite deprecation.  But you can definitely do it on the MongoTemplate by setting the read preference to secondary.

Comment: @Trisha, you are right that Slave-ok is just supported.  Do it in MongoTemplate programmatically to secondary also works, but is it too much overhead if I call setReadPreference() every time when I wanna get a collection from MongoTemplate?

Comment: No, you only have to set it on the collection (or database) once, then it will be used as the default on that collection (or database & therefore all collections) from then on,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding @Trisha's response in to an answer: "Do it in MongoTemplate programmatically" by setting the [`ReadPreference`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/index.html?com/mongodb/ReadPreference.html) to `SECONDARY`.

```
MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(...);
template.setReadPreference(com.mongodb.ReadPreference.SECONDARY);
```

Answer (score 9):

Declare the following bean

```
<bean id="readPreferenceSecondary" class="com.mongodb.TaggableReadPreference.SecondaryReadPreference">
</bean>
```

and

you inject this in your mongotemplate

```
<bean id="mongoTemplateProdDb" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" >
        <property name="readPreference" ref="readPreferenceSecondary"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using spring-data-mongodb and have some requirement to use multiple Read Preferences based on find query, you can create multiple Mongo Templates and/or Repositories like

```
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {
            "com.you.repo.package" }, mongoTemplateRef = "mongoTemplateOne")    
    @Configuration
    public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean(name="mongoTemplateOne")
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplateOne() throws UnknownHostException {
        MongoTemplate templateOne = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI("YOUR_MONGO_URL")));
        templateOne.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());

        //setting WriteConcern but not relevant for this thread
        templateOne.setWriteConcernResolver(yourWriteConcernResolver());
        return templateOne;
    }

    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplateTwo")
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplateTwo() throws UnknownHostException {
        MongoTemplate templateTwo = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI("YOUR_MONGO_URL")));
        templateTwo.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());
        return templateTwo;
    }


    private WriteConcernResolver yourWriteConcernResolver() {
        return action -> {
            if (action.getCollectionName()
                    .equals("your_collecton")
                    && (action.getMongoActionOperation() == MongoActionOperation.SAVE
                            || action.getMongoActionOperation() == MongoActionOperation.UPDATE)) {
                return WriteConcern.MAJORITY;
            }
            return action.getDefaultWriteConcern();
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you have more than one secondary (replica-set) you can be more specific and tell the mongo driver explicitly which of the secondaries you want to read from, using [tags](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/Mongo.setReadPref/).

On the mongo side you run this command:

```
db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondaryPreferred',
                          [{"tagName":"TagVal1"},
                            {"tagName":"TagVal2"},
                            {}])
```

In the code it looks like this:

```
MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(...)
template.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred("your DBObject that reflect your mongo tag names");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more way to do this using Mongo Repositories

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    public String mongoUri;


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.database");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClientSettings(MongoClientSettings.Builder builder) {
        builder.applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(mongoUri)).readPreference(ReadPreference.secondary());
    }

}
```

sample app available @
https://github.com/prashanthmadi/cosmosdb-mongodb-readpreference-springboot-java/blob/main/src/main/java/azure/cosmosdb/mongodb/spring/cosmosdbmongodb/ApplicationConfig.java

Answer (score 0):

If there is a need to mix between primary and secondary for reads depending on the collection, you can set the `ReadPreference` on the `DBCollection` object. This helps to avoid complex multiple `MongoTemplate` configuration. Instead, set collection level preference like below once in the application lifetime.  All the reads for that specific collection will go to secondary, while for other collections it goes to primary.

```
DBCollection dbCollection = mongoTemplate.getCollection(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(collection));
dbCollection.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());
```

If you want to know different options to achieve it, please check [Spring data mongodb secondary reads](https://ttechlearning.blogspot.com/2019/01/spring-data-mongodb-secondary-node-reads.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of [spring-mongo-2.0.xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-2.0.xsd), `slave-ok` has been entirely removed, but support has been added for XML config of `ReadPreference`. Here's the XML from the original question translated for the current XSD:

```
<mongo:mongo-client host="mongo.sample.com" port="30000">
     <mongo:client-options read-preference="SECONDARY_PREFERRED" />
</mongo:mongo-client>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can define at the query level with annotation in the repository interface:

```
@Meta(flags = CursorOption.SECONDARY_READS)
Stream<MyClass> findBySomeField(String someField);
```

Which is really useful when using spring generated queries from method names or annotations like **@Query** or **@Aggregation**

Comment: Nice! Doesn't answer the question directly but this is the way to do it in modern spring-data-mongo repositories!